# Bootstrap 3 - Replace button on mobile view

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
      <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
     <!-- desktop -->
      <li><a href="#" class="visible-md visible-lg">Reason 2</a></li>
     <!-- mobile -->
      <li><a href="onClick:abc();" class="visible-xs visible-sm">Reason 3</a></li>

    </ul>
```

What is the best practice with Bootstrap for replace elements (button, div, text ecc) for different devices?

Comment: What is the reason, do they act the same?

Comment: No, "reason 2" it's for pc only, "reason 3" it's for mobile only.

Comment: Then using the helper classes `visible-*` and `hidden-*` will be best practice if you really want other tags to be visible. If you want just perform other layout changes then use `media-queries` to alter css styles based on device.

Answer (score 1):

add `.visible-lg` for `<li>reason2</li>` and add `.visible-sm` for `<li>reason3</li>`.